# Regarding MS ajax client side javascript API

Tags: ajax

i am not very much familiar of MS ajax client side javascript API so i search google but did not get any url from where i can have tutorial like sort of for MS ajax client side javascript API. as example Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance(). this piece of code is related with MS-Ajax client side API. if anyone knows then please refer me.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference for the client-side library is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397536.aspx). Code examples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398976.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386571.aspx).